# Diagnostic Hub Tools cannot run

Tags: debugging, windows-7, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging

I'm trying to remotely attach to a process to try and trap a system critical bug.

I have the remote debugging monitor for VS2015 running on the clients machine. I can see the process I want to attach to, and when I do the debugger starts. The Diagnostic Tools wont start properly with this error:

```
Diagnostic Hub Tools cannot run because a required update to Windows is not installed. To resolve this issue, install the required update from 'http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2882822'.
```

I downloaded the update for my machine and for the remote machine (both Windows 7), but when I try to run it apparently the update has already been installed.

What is going on? I'm going a bit spare about this as its stopping me from sorting out a major bug.